# How to test the $.ajax success handler

Tags: jquery, ajax, jasmine, sinon, spy

Some portion of code is still using the old **success** handler which is currently making it difficult to test the lines inside them.

Below is my sample function:

```
function updateXYZExemption(partyId, payload) {

        if (!partyId) {
            throw new Error('partyId is required');
        }

        return $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'PUT',
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            url: config.urls.updateXYZExemptionUrl.replace(/\{partyId\}/, partyId),
            headers: {
                'If-Match': eTag
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
                if (request.getResponseHeader('ETag')) {
                    eTag = request.getResponseHeader('ETag');
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I am able to test that this function returns a promise but the function which is assigned to success property is not reachable.

Comment: then make it reachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the function to its own testable unit:

```
var myFunction = function (data, textStatus, request) {
    if (request.getResponseHeader('ETag')) {
        eTag = request.getResponseHeader('ETag');
    }
};
```

Then you can invoke that function independently, supply it mocks, and validate that its internal logic interacts with those mocks as expected and produces the expected results/effects.

You can use it as the success handler just by referencing the function:

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    success: myFunction,
    //...
});
```

This effectively separates the logic being tested (the function) from the framework plumbing (the call to `$.ajax()`).  The framework plumbing itself is of lower value for unit testing, since at that point you're really just testing someone else's code (the framework's).